# when i start my node.js server it get start but gave some error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

```
    var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Article = require('./models/articale');


mongoose.connect('/home/tentron/mongodb/LocalHost/nodekb');
var db = mongoose.connection;

// check for connection 

db.once('open', function(){
  console.log('connected to db.....');
});
//check for db error

db.on('error', function(err){
  console.log(err);
});

//Init app
var app = express();

// load view Engine 

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine','pug');

// home route

app.get('/', function(_req , res){
  Article.find({}, function(err,articles){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
    else{
        res.render('index',{
        title:'shashank home page',
        articles : articles,
      });
    }
  });
});

app.get('/views/add', function(req , res){
  res.render('add_artical', {
    title : 'add artical'
  });
});


//start server 
app.listen(3000,function(){
  console.log("your server is now ready at port number 3000...");

});
```

error when i start server

> [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
>           [nodemon] starting `node index.js`
>           your server is now ready at port number 3000...
>           **(node:8456) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid schema, e
>           xpected `mongodb` or `mongodb+srv`**
>               at module.exports (/home/tentron/Desktop/web-development-tutorial/
>           nodejs/projects /node_prject1/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongo
>           db/lib/url_parser.js:21:21)
>               at connect (/home/tentron/Desktop/web-development-tutorial/nodejs/
>           projects /node_prject1/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/
>           mongo_client.js:880:3)
>               at connectOp (/home/tentron/Desktop/web-development-tutorial/nodej
>           s/projects /node_prject1/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/li
>           b/mongo_client.js:270:3)
>               at executeOperation (/home/tentron/Desktop/web-development-tutoria
>           l/nodejs/projects /node_prject1/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mon
>           godb/lib/utils.js:420:24)
>               at MongoClient.connect (/home/tentron/Desktop/web-development-tuto
>           rial/nodejs/projects /node_prject1/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/
>           mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:261:10)
>               at Promise (/home/tentron/Desktop/web-development-tutorial/nodejs/
>           projects /node_prject1/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:436:12)
>               at new Promise ()
>               at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/home/tentron/Desktop/web-
>           development-tutorial/nodejs/projects /node_prject1/node_modules/mongoo
>           se/lib/connection.js:433:19)
>               at Mongoose.connect (/home/tentron/Desktop/web-development-tutoria
>           l/nodejs/projects /node_prject1/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:212
>           :15)
>               at Object. (/home/tentron/Desktop/web-development-tutor
>           ial/nodejs/projects /node_prject1/index.js:7:10)
>               at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
>               at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:7
>           13:10)
>               at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
>               at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
>               at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
>               at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:744:10)
>           (node:8456) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise reject
>           ion. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async funct
>           ion without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not han
>           dled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
>           (node:8456) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections
>            are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handle
>           d will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you use a bad-formed connection string.

It should be something like,

```
 mongodb://localhost:27017/nodekb
```

Comment: but i am using linux mint  so i use /home/tentron/mongodb/LocalHost/nodekb
can u plz tell me what should i write

Comment: should be the same with linux as well

Comment: just try to connect using robomongo

Comment: thanku brother " mongodb://localhost:27017/nodekb" it work. actually i did not know that it is same in linux so thaku